# Error in IB Gateway websockets "No accounts" with code 500

Tags: java, interactive-brokers, tws

I am using the IB Gateway to create a web portal. Followed the instructions from https://interactivebrokers.github.io/cpwebapi/ for local setup, everything is working fine on my local system but on production the websockets are giving error {error: 'No accounts', code: 500} even after successful login to IBKR. It shows authenticated as true when I access endpoints v1/api/tickle and v1/api/iserver/auth/status.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having same problem. Have you resolved? My problem is on a AWS EC2 server -- maybe somehow related to that?

Comment: Update for others that may bump into this: I recreated the instance from scratch and the error went away.